# Gap in the Section names

Tags: sectioning

Helo,I did not change anything about section type or anything but somehow after a certain section all sections and subsections are named with so much gap I could not find any solution for this.I would be so greatefull If anyone could help me.Thanks for your effort.
[image: example]

Comment: Hi, could you please add a compilable code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am writing a book and in only one chapter I have this issue I have searched for a similar problem but I could not find any so I am lost

Comment: Yes, this is strange, so in order to understand what is happening we need an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)! :)

Comment: My bet goes to an improperly used command instead of an environment. The behavior can be reproduced by setting `\parfillskip` to 0pt. Are you perhaps loading `ragged2e` and using its features?

Comment: I solved the Issue normally when there is an error in the code side It simply does not load the pdf file but my code was like this
Begin<center>
Code here.
...
When you dont add “end<center>”
It still compiles the program but an error occurs like I had.